# mingw32-make implementation of gnu-make can not remove files on windows

Tags: mingw, gnu-make

I am using the mingw32 implementation of gnu-make to port a C++ application from Linux to Windows.

mingw32-make.exe can compile the application correctly, exactly as on Linux, but for some reasom the `clean` command does not work. The relevant section of the makefile are:

```
#Where temporary object files are stored
ODIR=obj
#Where the final application is stored
OUTDIR=bin
OUTNAME=application.exe

...

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -Force ./$(OUTDIR)/$(OUTNAME)
    rm -Force ./$(ODIR)/*.o
```

Typing `mingw32-make clean` in the windows terminal gives the following output.

```
rm -Force ./bin/application.exe
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -Force ./bin/application.exe, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
makefile:37: recipe for target 'clean' failed
mingw32-make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

However, if I manually type the commands, it works exactly as it should:

```
rm -Force ./bin/application.exe
rm -Force ./obj/*.o
```

And then the files in question are gone.

But that is exactly what `mingw32-make` said was impossible, and I do know that the issue is not that the constants  `OUTDIR`,`ODIR` or `OUTNAME` are wrong, because  `mingw32-make` can perfectly fine compile the program and put the things in correct locations.

What is the difference, does make not have permission to delete files?

Comment: You need to set your `PATH` so it can find the POSIX tools like `rm`, which are not standard Windows tools.  Apparently whatever shell you are invoking `make` from, doesn't have those on the `PATH` or else your makefile is changing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use a bash shell like [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) that supports *nix commands line `rm` or change your `Makefile` to detect if it's running on Windows and the use `del` instead of `rm`. The best way is to set a variable to the correct deletion command for the detected build platform.

If you compile a lot of projects with source written by others the [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) shell is your easiest option as it requires no changes to `Makefile`.